# The variable in namespace of TCL

Tags: variables, namespaces, tcl

I have a question about variables in namespace of TCL.

I have two .tcl files, a.tcl, b.tcl, I define the same global variable in these two files, for example:

a.tcl

```
variable same "hello1"
```

b.tcl

```
variable same "hello2"
proc use {} {
   puts same
}
```

but in b.tcl, I try to define a proc to use the variable "`same`", is it a conflicts? which same is used in proc use()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears from your question (and comments to Donal) that you believe that files have anything to do with namespaces. This thought is incorrect.

a.tcl

```
variable same "hello a" ;# global namespace
```

b.tcl

```
variable same "hello b" ;# global namespace
proc use {} {
    variable same ;# reads from the global namespace
    puts $same    ;# will puts "hello a" or "hello b" depending on whether
                  ;# a.tcl is sourced after b.tcl or not
}
```

c.tcl

```
namespace eval ::not_the_global {
    variable same "hello c" ;# a different namespace, and a different variable than
                            ;# the one from the previous two files
}
```

d.tcl

```
namespace eval ::not_the_global {
    proc use {} {     ;# a different use proc from the one in b.tcl
        variable same ;# the variable defined in this namespace in c.tcl
        puts $same    ;# will output "hello c" no matter is a.tcl or b.tcl 
                      ;# were sourced
    }
}
```

The moral of the story being that the file that code is in is irrelevant, to namespaces or anything else. For a command or variable to be in a separate namespace, it must explicitly be placed in there.

Answer (score 3):

The `use` procedure will be in the same namespace as the `same` variable (which file the code is in is 100% orthogonal to which namespace it creates commands and variables in). *However*, the body of `use` will not have access to the variables of the namespace by default because all procedure-declared variables are local variables by default. This means that to get access to `same`, you should bring it into scope with `variable`, probably without the value-initialization argument:

```
proc use {} {
    variable same
    puts $same
}
```

You could also use the fully-qualified name of the variable directly, but that tends to be slower (especially in a loop).

---

Before you ask, I'd expect the above code to cause `use` to print *either* “hello1” or “hello2”, depending on which order a.tcl and b.tcl are `source`d. Any namespacing has to be done explicitly through a `namespace eval ::someNsName { ...script... }`. You'd probably put such a thing around the rest of the contents of each of your script files. It's usually considered bad form to write code that depends excessively on the order you source files, mostly because it tends to be quite a lot more difficult to debug…

Comment: what you mean by "The use procedure will be in the same namespace as the same variable (which file the code is in is 100% orthogonal to which namespace it creates commands and variables in)."? do you mean: the use procedure can not see the variable same in a.tcl? only same in b.tcl can be seen?

Comment: @ratzip I mean that files and namespaces have nothing at all to do with each other in their mechanism. All `source` does is read the file's contents into a string and then `eval` that string. (Well, it also sets `info script` up. A small refinement.) It does _nothing_ with namespaces if that is not written explicitly inside the file. This means that a.tcl and b.tcl _will_ see the same variables if sourced from the same context.

Comment: Moreover, as a matter of good practice, it is best to be explicit with namespaces so your code doesn't change behavior when you run it from different contexts or in different orders. You don't _have_ to but it it is much easier for you…

Comment: yes, you are right, it has nothing to do with namespace if it is not written explicitly,  in this case, the global variable same defined in both file can be seen by proc use? but when we call the proc use, which variable same is used by proc use?

Comment: @ratzip: If you don't say otherwise (via `global`, `upvar` or `variable`) a variable will be local to the procedure call.

Answer (score 1):

Forget about the two files for a moment. Lets assume you just have a single file and the content is:

```
variable x hello ;# this is a global variable.

proc use {} {
  puts $x
}
```

This should result in an error that says something like `$x` is undefined. Why? Because Tcl, unlike C, doesn't import anything into a function that you don't ask it to. Let me say that again: tcl procs doesn't see global or namespace variables that you don't tell it to see.

So, to import global variables the traditional way is to use the `global` command:

```
variable x hello

proc use {} {
  global x ;# import $x into this proc
  puts $x
}
```

this should work.

With namespaces of course the word `global` doesn't make sense so the `variable` command was created to allow procs defined in a namespace to see namespaced variables:

```
namespace eval foo {
  variable x hello

  proc use {} {
    variable x ;# import $x into this proc
    puts $x
  }
}
```

There is also another way to import global and namespaced variables without explicitly using either `global` or `variable`: just specify the full namespace. The global namespace is simply `::` so the following also works:

```
variable x hello

proc use {} {
  puts $::x
}
```

and of course:

```
namespace eval foo {
  variable x hello

  proc use {} {
    puts $foo::x
  }
}
```